# Environment variable with different value

Tags: environment-variables

I operate a windows system with several applications, that all need a special home variable.

But if I set this "home" variable, all applications use the same value. Is there a way to set this variable independent of application?

Comment: This implies, that I can set the variable before starting the process. But the applications are run as services, so I don't have a start script where I can set the variables.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention these were services. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2728574/895782.